# Эффект для блока при скролле

Tags: jquery

Допустим есть блок с текстом, блок имеет свойство `overflow: hidden auto;`.
Хочу реализовать следующее:

Если есть сколл, добавлять псевдоэлемент `::after` который будет делать тень внизу родителя, типо намекая, что внизу что-то есть, можно скроллить.

При скролле вниз, добавляется псевдоэлемент `::before`, который будет делать тень вверху родителя, ну думаю понятно на что намекать будет :)

Естественно проверять, если доскроллил до конца\начала, отключать псевдоэлемент отвечающий за тень.

Собстна как реализовать я догадываюсь, знаю что нельзя управлять псевдоэлементами через JQ, но этом можно реализовать на классах (`.top-shadow`, `.bottom-shadow`).

Что же я не могу понять:
1. Как правильно записать обработчик скролла, именно текущего элемента, т.к. их может быть несколько на одной странице.
2. Как проверять на "начало" и "конец" скролла.

---

**UPD**

Подумав, я всё таки смог что-то написать, но вот столкнулся с проблемой..

```js
function ScrollBlockEffect() {
  $('.scroll-block').each(function(){
   let wrap = $(this).find('.scroll-wrap'),
      thisH = $(this).height(),
        wrapH = wrap.height();
    if(wrapH > thisH) $(this).addClass('bottom-shadow');
  }).bind('scroll', function(){
    let wrap = $(this).find('.scroll-wrap'),
      thisH = $(this).height(),
        wrapH = wrap.height(),
      scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollY>0) {
     $(this).addClass('top-shadow');
      if(scrollY==(wrapH-thisH)) $(this).removeClass('bottom-shadow'); else $(this).addClass('bottom-shadow');
    } else if(scrollY==0) $(this).removeClass('top-shadow');
  });
}
ScrollBlockEffect();
```

```css
.scroll-block {display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden auto; position: relative;}
.scroll-wrap {display: block; width: 100%;}
.top-shadow::before, .bottom-shadow::after {content: ''; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; pointer-events: none;}
.top-shadow::before {box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -20px #000 inset;}
.bottom-shadow::after {box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px #000 inset;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------->
<div class="scroll-block">
  <div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non.</div>
</div>
```

.. как "прижать" псевдоэлементы к границам родителя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извиняйте, что не jQuery, но я вижу решение так:

```js
function fMore(e) {
  let oFake = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.scroll-shadow');
  oFake.style.width = 'calc(100% - ' + (e.target.offsetWidth - e.target.scrollWidth) + 'px)';
  oFake.style.boxShadow = `
    inset 0 2.2em 1.5em ${(e.target.scrollTop == 0) ? '-10' : '-1'}em #fff, 
    inset 0 -2.2em 1.5em ${(e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop > e.target.clientHeight) ? '-1' :  '-10'}em #fff
  `;
};
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-block')).forEach(function(e) {
  let oScrollWrap = e.querySelector('.scroll-wrap');
  let oFake = document.createElement('DIV');
  oFake.className = 'scroll-shadow';
  e.appendChild(oFake);
  oScrollWrap.addEventListener('scroll', fMore);
  oScrollWrap.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
});
```

```css
.scroll-block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  width: 32%;
  border: 2px solid #fa0;
}

.scroll-wrap {
  height: inherit;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroll-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  transition: box-shadow .6s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-block">
  <div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-block">
  <div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-block">
  <div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante
    risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula.
  </div>
</div>
```

*PS.: Единственная проблема, которую не смог победить - небольшая задержка перед появлением тени.*

Comment: а всё равно хорошо получилось, хоть и задержка с тенью

Comment: Отличное решение. В принципе в моём коде тоже задержка тени есть, скорее всего из-за обработчика скролла.. Что если "добавлять" на пару пикселей раньше, чем "скролл" добирается до границы?

Answer (score 2):

Пришлось использовать совсем другую "технику".

Вот такой вариант получился:

```js
function ScrollBlockEffect() {
 let animTime = 'fast';
  $('.scroll-block').each(function(){
   let wrap = $(this).find('.scroll-wrap'),
      thisH = $(this).height(),
        wrapH = wrap.height();
    if(wrapH > thisH) $(this).css('box-shadow', shadowCss(0,1,20));
  }).bind('scroll', function(){
    let wrap = $(this).find('.scroll-wrap'),
      thisH = $(this).height(),
        wrapH = wrap.height(),
      scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollY>0) {
     $(this).css('box-shadow', shadowCss(1,1,20));
      if(scrollY==(wrapH-thisH))
       $(this).css('box-shadow', shadowCss(1,0,20));
      else
       $(this).css('box-shadow', shadowCss(1,1,20));
    } else if(scrollY == 0) $(this).css('box-shadow', shadowCss(0,1,20));
  });
  
  function shadowCss(top,bottom,size) {
   let res = ('0 '+(size*top)+'px '+size+'px -'+size+'px inset, 0 -'+(size*bottom)+'px '+size+'px -'+size+'px inset');
   return res;
  }
}
ScrollBlockEffect();
```

```css
.scroll-block {display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden auto; position: relative; transition: box-shadow linear .2s;}
.scroll-wrap {display: block; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------->
<div class="scroll-block">
  <div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.scroll-wrap').on('scroll', function() {
        if(Math.round($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight(), 10) >= Math.round($(this)[0].scrollHeight, 10)) {
            $(this).addClass("no-shadow");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("no-shadow");
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.scroll-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 30px -10px #000000;
}

.no-shadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tristique nisl sed cursus vehicula. Etiam ac ultricies metus. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pulvinar ante risus, ac efficitur purus elementum non.</div>
```

Comment: Совсем не то, что описано в вопросе..

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, не вижу проблем подправить этот код под свою задачу, на мой взгляд он куда чище и логичнее чем представил ты. Концепция сайта ведь не "напишите за меня код", а подсказать варианты решения.

Comment: Вопрос читали? Я не прошу написать код, даже сам думал над кодом. В Вашем решение вижу только "добавление тени при скролле", я вроде конкретно описал задачу, а мой ответ в виде кода иллюстрирует её.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 в "конкретно описаной задаче" через каждые два слова "псевдоэлемент" и даже в UPD вопрос как прижать "псевдоэлемент" ну и итоговый код просто вырви глаз уже правда без псевоэлементов. Не вижу проблем в моем варианте поменять нижнюю тень на верхнюю. И да, ответ я написал до второго кода, просто запостил позже.

Comment: Первое что в голову пришло - использование псевдоэлементов, но проще было использовать чисто стили, ибо псевдоэлемент не прижать. "Вырви глаз" интересно, что же плохого в коде?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, у меня сомнения что ты сам свой код через месяцок сможешь сходу прочитать и понять, а уж если кто другой в него полезет икать будешь :)

Comment: Удачи использовать "мне нужно создать самолёт" -> "вот чертёж танка".